# Add/remove <li> element from the ul javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild, removechild

I am new in JavaScript and still learning various things. Right now i'm stuck with adding and removing li elements from the list. I did the exercise just fine using jQuery, but now have difficulties with the pure JS version of the same task.

The main idea is to add a new li element by clicking on the button, and remove the the element by clicking on the X button right next to it. I have tried using 'this' and other advices mentioned in similar questions here on Stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me. Could you, please, guide me what am I doing wrong?

P.S. the adding function seems to be working in snippet, but console logs error: cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null.

```js
//declaring the variables
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var add = document.getElementById('add');

//adding a new element to the list
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
  list.appendChild(newElement);
  newElement.innerHTML= "I am a new element<button class='btn'>X</button>";
});

//removing the clicked element
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  list.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
```

```css
ul li {
  decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:  'Avant Garde', Avantgarde, 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#add {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 280px;
  font-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}

#add:hover {
  background-color: #28364d;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#add:active {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
}

.btn{
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.btn:active {
position: relative;
bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <ul id="list">
        <li class="element">I am a new element<button class="btn">X</button></li>
        <li class="element">I am a new element<button class="btn">X</button></li>
        <li class="element">I am a new element<button class="btn">X</button></li>
        <li class="element">I am a new element<button class="btn">X</button></li>
        <li class="element">I am a new element<button class="btn">X</button></li>
      </ul>

    <button id="add">Add an element to the list</button>
</div>
```

Comment: to solve your immediate problem, as well as your future problems with the new elements, look into something called "event delegation" https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: Thank you, I definitely will!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns a non-live collection:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
```

Which means that it will only contain the objects which exist at the point of the method call. You need to call `getElementsByClassName()` after the creation of the new `li` elements, and attach the EventListeners on the *invidual* buttons. Just remember not to put an EventListener twice on the buttons.

#### A nicer solution

Better yet: do not use `getElementsByClassName()`, just attach the event handler directly in the function, in which you create the new button. That way, you don't have to worry about pre-existing event handlers:

```
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
    list.appendChild(newElement);
    newElement.innerHTML= "I am a new element<button class='btn'>X</button>";
    newElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `btn` is a node list of elements, not an element, so you can't attach an event to an array. You need to iterate through them:

```
for(i=0; i < btn.length; i++) {
   btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      list.parentNode.removeChild(this);
   });
}
```

Comment: While correct, This won't work in the long term. He's adding elements dynamically.

Comment: That's another task, I can improve the answer, but OP is asking for the `cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null.`. You're right in dinamic elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am learning too and this was a good little challenge as a newcomer. Thanks to rlemon for pointing us in the right direction with that article link. I learnt something here.

In case you were interested what I arrived at:
https://jsfiddle.net/nyxhj0tg/1/

JS:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var add = document.getElementById('add');

//adding a new element to the list
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var newElement = document.createElement('LI');
  list.appendChild(newElement);
  newElement.innerHTML= "I am a new element<button class='btn'>X</button>";

});

list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
        console.log("Button ", e, " was clicked!");
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
    }
});
```